# Cannot use testflight with builds uploaded from XCode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode, build, testflight

Here is the warning/error I get:

"Some builds are missing the beta entitlement, or were uploaded with a beta version of Xcode, and cannot be tested"

I am not using a Beta version of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: same issue here. And I had previously uploaded ones with it.

Comment: same here. It was working fine till morning (Oct 5, 2015).

Comment: same here. Halpo you found any solution ?

Comment: Just wait a couple of hours and the warning will disappear

Comment: Same thing happened to me...

Comment: Same here, I just got this trying to use testflight and I was able to upload previous versions without any issues until now.  Apple is a mess these days.

Comment: Waited a full night, but then it worked.

Comment: waited 3 days - still did not disappear???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The warnings eventually disappeared

Comment: After how much time did they disappear?

Comment: It's been 3 hours for me...still waiting.

Comment: I have one processing for more than 24 hours. Yay.

Comment: It’s been 6 hours and I’m still waiting. Just hate this.

Comment: How do you add these beta entitlements to avoid this?!

Answer (score 0):

For people who still export and upload thru application loader,

when you export, make sure to select **Save for iOS App Store Deployment**

[image]